# How to click button to increase number of value with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm looking for a PHP function (or "*whatever works*" function) that will make the value `0` go up every time my `DIV` is clicked and at the same time, save that new value on a `PHP file`.
Help me with these:
1. Click "#myDiv" to make value go up by 1
2. When "#myDiv" is clicked save new value on the PHP File (so I can execute it elsewhere)
3. Make the *new* saved value appear on another `DIV "#otherDiv" when "#myDiv" is clicked.

*I'm doing this because I've been looking for a counter that saves the value but it doesn't work with just javascript or jquery so I hope that it can happen with PHP.*
**I'm willing to try any other method that works better (possibly with AJAX?)

Any help is appreciated. If you don't understand what I'm looking for, ask me questions, thanks!**

Comment: Post what you have tried out so far?

Comment: Share Your **Tried Code**.

Comment: I have tried using cookies but I don't want to rely on cookies because I could accidentally delete them and the saved value would be gone. Also I have tried to use the PHP post method but I wasn't able to figure it out by myself because I'm not a PHP expert.

Comment: you need to use jquery and ajax and php. create one click event and incriment value by 1. so you will get latest count and pass that data using ajax and update value in database

Comment: You want to increment a server side variable with a client side action which isn't the best plan. Can you be more specific in why you want to do this? Is it worth incrementing a value in a database on the button click and echoing this value out via php?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable plan @LaljiNakum i would appreciate id you set up the functions for me.

Comment: @Matt the whole Idea is to click on a button that makes a value go up and every time I reload the page, that new number wont change back to 0.

Comment: @Graphicoding In that case you want to: On button click, update a database value, and then retrieve the value. When you want it 'saved/appear' on another file, just run the retrieval code on that php page. and echo it in the new div

Comment: @Matt Yes, that is exactly what I want. But instead I was wondering if I could use the PHP file instead of the database to automatically update to the new value?

Comment: @Graphicoding How long does this value need to last? Can you use a 3rd file, maybe text file, to store the value in for the other page? It depends on what this value is being used for as it will end up 'disappearing' eventually without storing it properly.

Comment: @Matt I am trying to avoid cookies because like you said, eventually it will disappear, that is why I want to update the value on the php file but if this can't be done, using a database isn't a bad choice neither. This value needs to last for a long time and I need to execute it to my Index file so it can be displayed, i dont think a txt file would work.

Comment: Okay, using a database. Lets see what we can do. Will write up an answer now :).

Comment: Okay thank you very much for the useful questions matt!

Comment: @Graphicoding One last question - does it have to be a div? Or can it be a form with a button ha..

Comment: Im looking forward to whatever is possible because it has been bugging me for the last few hours :p @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea keeping it very simple: page1.php, button clicked. databased is updated. number is viewable on page2.php

demo: http://themooliecommunity.com/TEST/page1.php

Only the pages set out below are in this folder.

dbconnect.php

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

page1.php

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';
?>
<form method="post" action="increment.php">
   <input type="submit" Value="increment" name="increment" />
</form>
```

increment.php

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "UPDATE `table` SET value = value+1";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    header("Location: ./page2.php");
?>
```

getdata.php

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT value FROM `table`";
    $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $number = $row['value'];
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    include 'getdata.php';
    echo $number;
?>
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table`
--

INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `value`) VALUES
(0, 0);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `table`
--
ALTER TABLE `table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: Are they all separate php files or do some go together?

Comment: all separate files. for now you can keep them in the same folder, however when you come to a live environment. Put dbconnect.php in the root of your webserver outside of public_html, so no one can access your login details

Comment: Works like a charm! I will move some functions around to make it feel better like redirect page1 back to page1 and automatically show the $number. Thank you very much Matt! Is there a way we can keep in contact?

Comment: Glad it works for you Graphic :). I'm an avid gamer so if you have steam add me :) http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124567784/ Otherwise, add me on skype: matt.barber94

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like below :

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select divcount from user");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<html>
    <title>Count DIV Click</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(function() {
            $("#myDiv").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "data_update.php",
                    data: "curcnt="+ $('#display').text(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#display").text(html);
                    }
                });
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" style="cursor:pointer">My div</div>
        <div id="display"><?php echo $row['divcount']; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

db.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

data_update.php

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    if(isSet($_POST['curcnt']))
    {
        $curcnt = $_POST['curcnt'] + 1;
        if($_POST['curcnt']=='0' || $_POST['curcnt']=='')
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"insert into user(divcount) values('".$curcnt."')");
        }
        else 
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"update user set divcount='".$curcnt."'");
        }
        echo $curcnt;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '0';
    }
    exit;
?>
```

SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `divcount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```